# How to include "Assemblyversion" in "AssemblyName" example: "Myapp_1.1.exe"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build

I am looking at the adding the version(available in "assemblyinfo.cs") details to the AssemblyName in a C# project.
I want to to perform this as i want my final exe name to contain both the assemblyname and version details like "MYAPP_1.1.exe"

How can i achieve this?

1) I do not want to hardcode the Assemblyname
2) i have tried using the pre-build script. I was able to achieve the "Version" details from assemblyinfo.cs,but i am unable to modify the "AssemblyName" from the pre-build.

What am i missing and how can i achieve this functionality

Comment: but to rename the final executable shouldn't you use the post-build? In the pre-build you do not have the output files yet of course.

Comment: +1 for creating post-build action

Answer (score 0):

If you install InstallShield LE and build an install package with it, it has options to override the file name.

In the project:

- Open, Organize Your Setup --> General Information
- Set the name you want for the file in General --> Product Name